# Azure App Attach MSIX file - invalid logo error?

Tags: azure, msix

We are trying to add an MSIX package to an Azure VM using App Attach. However, when we attach the package, we get this error:

```
ActivityId: cd549d32-6bbb-48cb-a422-1451bbf6481d Error: MSIX Package contains an invalid logo (Code: 400)
```

This is unfortunately all the information it gives us.

What does this error relate to and how is it resolved?